# retrieving local storage items with random number added to the key

Tags: jquery, local-storage

In a shopping cart, I am adding the products to the local storage so that when a payment fails the customer can click a button that then repopulates the shopping cart so they can try again.

I add to local storage with these codes:

```
  $( ".terms-conditions" ).click(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('LinkURL' + ranNr, rdsLinkURL);
    localStorage.setItem('LinkTitle' + ranNr, rdsLinkTitle);
    localStorage.setItem('LinkOrderURL' + ranNr, rdsLinkOrderURL);
    localStorage.setItem('OrderAmount' + ranNr, rdsOrderAmount);
  });
```

These codes are inside a `$('.rdsubs-cart-name').each` method and this is saved fine in LocalStorage with each item being nicely grouped under their own number. But now I want to retrieve it and this retrieval takes place on a new webpage and therefore I can't use:

```
$( ".btn-repopulate-shopping-cart" ).click(function() {
  console.log(localStorage.getItem('LinkURL' + ranNr));
});
```

Because `ranNr` is not defined. So I was thinking cant we retrieve all the key values **starting with** `LinkURL`.

So the above that is the goal and to get there I already tried a couple of things but to no avail.

`console.log(localStorage.getItem([^='LinkURL']));`
`console.log(localStorage.getItem('LinkURL*'));`
`console.log(localStorage.getItem([^'LinkURL*']));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [String.startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startswith) like following

```
localStorage.setItem('LinkURL1', "abc"); 
localStorage.setItem('LinkURL2', "def"); 

let result = Object.keys(localStorage).filter(v => v.startsWith("LinkURL"));
console.log(result); // ["LinkURL1", "LinkURL2"]

result.forEach(k => console.log(localStorage.getItem(k))); // paints abc and def
```

Comment: I was just going to ask to retrieve the results. Thank you for this update. Going to test it right away!

Comment: This is it works perfectly I am going to read the links you provided that is super helpful. And having the working code also immediately is even better. Thank you so much!

Comment: @purple11111 - Glad to help you!

Comment: What if you wanted to output for instance the linkurl and the order amount together?

Comment: @purple11111 - Not clear with your question. Can you please help me with an example?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do this with Jquery but I'll try providing solution in javascript. Hope it'll help you out.

```
let allKeys = Object.keys(localStorage);
let filteredKeys = allKeys.filter(key => key.startsWith("LinkURL"));
let filteredValues = filteredKeys.map(filteredKey => 
localStorage.getItem(filteredKey))
```

Here allKeys will be the array of keys i.e array of string.
And filteredKeys is the array of keys(starting withLinkURL).
filteredValues is the array of all values corresponding to array filteredKeys .

Comment: Nice to also see a javascript way. It would be great if you could also make it show the values as it now displays the keys only. But thanks for helping. I am going to go with Nikhil's answer though. But you definitely deserve an upvote!

Comment: thanks dude, I thought that from keys you'll be able to dig out values. But I'll edit now.